# Singing and hearing quarter tones

Tags: voice, ear-training, hearing, rehearsal

I’ve just received a choir piece that contains some (rare) quarter tones on long held notes. For example, a B which slides into a Bᴓ (that's a half flat).

I’ve tried singing the part where it happens. Not for very long, I’ll admit, but with little success. It seems that my brain tends to put the pitch into a category it knows well: either I’m hearing a (low) B, or a (high) B♭. I’m never sure I’m singing the "right"<sup>1</sup> note.

How can I ensure that I’m actually singing this "right" note? Do any of you know of some tools out there that could help me train my ear?

---

1. I do realise that "right" here can actually have different meanings. Let's say 24-TET. Quite frankly, if I manage to consistently sing something that is not quite a B, nor quite a B♭, I’ll be satisfied anyway.

Comment: You could down load an app that is a tuner. InsTuner is a good one as it will show you how close you are to the note.

Comment: Be interesting to see what your choirmaster has to say about it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what piece is it?

Comment: You say long-held notes but you also say slide. I think you need to practice the slide. Sing up an ordinary scale, "doh re mi .."  When you get to the semitones, slow down and slide gradually from the E to the F and the B to the C.  If these are really slides then you don't have to settle on an intermediate tone, just slide through it.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It doesn't slide *through* the half tone. It's a portamento from a B to a B (half flat) that is then held for a few mesures.

Comment: Probably indeed there are two technical difficulties: 1. slide, 2. quarter tones. Practice them independently. Concerning quarter tones, a practice technique I know is to play B and Bb on an instrument (e.g. piano, or generate them on a computer), sing one, sing another, then try to sing the note in the middle, and repeat. After a while half tone starts to feel like a huge interval.

Comment: What is this piece, if I may ask?

Answer (score 2):

Start by using two regular keyboards which can be tuned, assuming you are a keyboardist. I would recommend two of these two get started

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/SA76--casio-sa-76-portable-arranger-keyboard

These were designed for use in music education in India; which in short means they can be tune freely up or down 100 cents (100 division of a half step).

Try regular tuning & 50 cents sharp for 1/4 tones first. Try singing quarter tones and half steps so you don't temporarily forget what half-steps 'sound like'. When I first started I was singing quarter tones so much I put them in place of half steps.

Here are two example files to get you started. Here is 4 octaves of quarter-tones.

https://soundcloud.com/user-142574024/microtonal-ear-training-14-tones-4-octaves-c2-c6

Here is something I have been calling 1/3 tone major. Basically 1/3 tones are 1/3 of a whole step so 3 equal 2 half steps. So this one goes: C, C-1/3#, D-1/3b, D, D 1/3#, E, F, F-1/3#, G-1/3b, G, G-1/3#, A-1/3b, A, A-1/3# B-1/3b, B, & C. Basically a major scale where you replace whole-steps with third-steps but keep the half-steps.

https://soundcloud.com/user-142574024/microtonal-ear-training-13-tone-major-see-description-below

These links might break... not sure if changing use name does that... will update in comment if so.